Datatable .column() not returning anything
I have the following code using datatables 1.10.18 (yes, I know, it's old code and updating the datatables version would require a lot of rewrites):
<table id='testtable' class='datatable'>
    <tr><td>Within value</td><td>Second column</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Without value</td><td>Second column</td></tr>
</table>

<script>
var testtable = $('#testtable').dataTable({
    paging: true,
    bLengthChange: true,
    bPaginate: true,
    bFilter: false,
    bSort: false,
    autoWidth: true,
    sDom: 'lrtp',
    columns: [
        { sTitle: 'ACTIVITY' },
        { sTitle: 'DATE' }
    ]
});
var table = $('#testtable').DataTable();
</script>

Dirt simple, bare bones. When I run table.data() in the console, I correctly get the array of data. So the information is correct, and it's accessible. However, when I run table.column(0) or any derivative function, I get no results. What I want to do is table.column(0).search('Within').draw(). When I attempt to run it, nothing changes.

As far as I can tell, I'm doing exactly the same thing as what's on https://datatables.net/examples/api/regex.html except that I'm doing it statically instead of dynamically. I've double- and triple-checked my code against the I don't understand why the .column() function isn't working, or anything after it. What am I doing wrong?

The solution is to remove the following option:
bFilter: false

(or to set it to true, which is the default).
The old bFilter option is now renamed to searching for DataTables version 1.10 onwards - although the old names can still be used (as in your code).
The documentation for searching clarifies that this option:

allows the search abilities of DataTables to be enabled or disabled.

So you have disabled searching (filtering) in your code. That is why you were not getting the expected DataTables result.

Just to also note:

"when I run table.column(0) or any derivative function, I get no results"

As you show in your screenshot you do get results - you get an object returned. You printed it to the console.
Looking at the API documentation for column(), it states:

Returns: DataTables API instance with selected column in the result set.

And that is exactly what you got.
One way to see the data in that column is:
console.log( table.column(0).data().toArray() );

That prints:
Array [ "Within value", "Without value" ]


Be aware that you do not need to define that table variable. You may need to do this for reasons not shown in the question, but instead you can do the simpler thing:


var testtable = $('#testtable').DataTable({
  paging: true,
  bLengthChange: true,
  bPaginate: true,
  //bFilter: false,
  bSort: false,
  autoWidth: true,
  sDom: 'lrtp',
  columns: [{
      sTitle: 'ACTIVITY'
    },
    {
      sTitle: 'DATE'
    }
  ]
});

testtable.column(0).search('Within').draw();
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Demo</title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.18/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.18/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://datatables.net/media/css/site-examples.css">

</head>

<body>

  <div style="margin: 20px;">

    <table id='testtable' class='datatable'>
      <tr>
        <td>Within value</td>
        <td>Second column</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Without value</td>
        <td>Second column</td>
      </tr>
    </table>

  </div>


</body>

</html>



You can run the above snippet for yourself.
I changed this:
var testtable = $('#testtable').dataTable({

to this:
var testtable = $('#testtable').DataTable({

It's a subtle change - lowercase d to uppercase D. You can read about the difference here:

note the difference between $( selector ).DataTable() and $( selector ).dataTable(). The former returns a DataTables API instance, while the latter returns a jQuery object.

So, your code was not returning a DataTables instance - hence you needed to create one using var table = $('#testtable').DataTable();. In my case, I already create a DataTables instance and assign it to testtable. No need to create the table variable. So, I removed it and used testtable everywhere, instead.

I see. Thank you, I'll mark this as the answer once I've had a chance to return to that page and verify it.
Is there a programmatic way to have search capabilities turned on but not show the search field, or do I need to just target it with css to hide it?

Use the DataTables dom option to hide the filter input field. Or, if you are using the latest version of DataTables, use the new layout option. There are also many Stack OVerflow questions and answers about using dom.
